# failed simple experiment with surfactant

Tags: water, home-experiment, surfactants

I wanted to show my son the effect of a surfactant.  So I filled two small glasses with tap-water, added a squirt of RinseAid to one and stirred.  Then I sprinkled powdered flour on both.  My hypothesis was that the powdered flour would sink much more quickly in the water-RinseAid mixture compared to the water because the RinseAid would lower the surface tension.  In fact, the experiment was a flop-- I could not see any difference in how fast the flour particles sank in the two glasses.  What went wrong?

Comment: How fast the particles would sink depends on viscosity. Surface tension would keep the particles floating. Try floating a sewing needle using a fork to float the needle. Then touch a finger to some dishwashing liquid and touch your finger to the surface of the water.